# I am predicting population for the next few years, how to I append predicted data to my original data set and then plot the full data set?

Tags: r, append, predict

**- This code works fine**

```
 FL.POP = read.csv("C:\\Users\\jevans\\Desktop\\Jessica School\\Florida population 2010-2019.csv", header = TRUE )
    Year <- as.numeric(FL.POP$Year)
    Population <- as.numeric(FL.POP$Population_Estimation)
    model<-lm(Population~Year)
    model
    plot(formula=(Population~Year),data=FL.POP,main='Florida Population')
    abline(reg=lm(formula=(Population~Year),data=FL.POP),col='red')
    summary(FL.POP)

    new.years<- data.frame(Year = c(2019,2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025))
    NewData<-predict(model,newdata = new.years)
    NewData
    new.pop<- data.frame(Population = c(NewData))
    new.pop
    new.years
```

**-I have not been able to append the new predictions and the new years to my original data so that I can plot it out.**

Comment: Did you try `rbind.data.frame(old_dataframe, new_dataframe)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FL.POP = read.csv("C:\\Users\\jevans\\Desktop\\Jessica School\\Florida population 2010-2019.csv", header = TRUE )

model<-lm(Population_Estimation ~ Year, data = FL.POP)
model
plot(Population_Estimation ~ Year, data=FL.POP, main = 'Florida Population')
abline(reg = model, col='red')

newdata<- data.frame(Year = c(2019,2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025))
pred <- predict(model, newdata = newdata)
newdata$Population_Estimation <- pred

FL.POP <- rbind(FL.POP, newdata)
```

If you want to overwrite the csv file along with the predictions,

```
write.csv(FL.POP, "C:\\Users\\jevans\\Desktop\\Jessica School\\Florida population 2010-2019.csv")
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:   Error in eval(predvars, data, env): numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

Comment: Updated the answer